# Trouble with ChatEngineCore in the Pubnub Angular2 Tutorial

Tags: angular, pubnub

I get the errors

"Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof ChatEngineCore'" and

"Property 'plugin' does not exist on type 'typeof ChatEngineCore'"

when I try to call ChatEngineCore.create and ChatEngineCore.plugin on the PubNub Angular2 Chatbot tutorial.

Any ideas? Am I missing something simple? Here is my code copied directly from PubNub's tutorial:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatEngineCore } from 'chat-engine';

@Injectable()
export class ChatEngine {
  instance: any;
  create: any;
  plugin: any;
  me: any = { state: {} };
  chat: any = {};
  chats: any[] = [];
  constructor() {
    // Make sure to import ChatEngine first!
    this.instance = ChatEngineCore.create({
      publishKey: 'MY-PUBLISH-KEY',
      subscribeKey: 'MY-SUBSCRIBE-KEY'
    },
    {
      debug: true,
      globalChannel: 'chat-engine-angular2-simple'
    });
    this.create = ChatEngineCore.create.bind(this);
    this.plugin = ChatEngineCore.plugin;
  }

  newChat(user) {
    // define a channel
    let chat = new Date().getTime();
    // create a new chat with that channel
    let newChat = new this.instance.Chat(chat);
    // we need to auth ourselves before we can invite others
    newChat.on('$.connected', () => {
      // this fires a private invite to the user
      newChat.invite(user);
      // add the chat to the list
      this.chats.push(newChat);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the tutorial link and the version of ChatEngine that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old issue but, as I've dealt with the same problem, may this workaround help anyone else.

As `ChatEngineCore` is declared globally, what I have done is removing its import, then instead called it directly from the `window` object:

`this.instance = window['ChatEngineCore'].create({ ... });`

Hopefully a future update of `chat-engine` package will solve this import error.

Answer (score 0):

ChatEngineCore has the property create and plugin but they are not present directly in it.

They are inside the prototype of the object instance of ChatEngineCore class.

So to access the we need to use commands:

```
ChatEngineCore.prototype.create()
ChatEngineCore.prototype.plugins
```